# Training Loss increases with the increase of data size and the train accuracy remains almost constant

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I am a newbie in ML. I am tryng to develop a LSTM model using time series data for a long time. I have tried several architectures of LSTM, but getting very large Loss and low accuracy. I  had so many null values in my data. i have removed any sequence(e.g 8 mins window) which has at least one null value. I used the code form https://machinelearningmastery.com/

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

here i excluded all the sequence which has null values. after excluding sequence of any null vlaues, it will look for next sequence

```
def split_datasetnormalized(dataset, timestamp):

    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[test_size:len(dataset), :]

    x = []
    y = []
    xp = []
    yp = []
    for i in range(len(train) - timestamp - 1):

        if len(train[i:i +
                     timestamp]) == timestamp and not np.isnan(train[i:i +
                                                                     timestamp +
                                                                     1]).any():
            trainx = train[i:i + timestamp, 0]
            trainy = train[i + timestamp:i + timestamp + 1, 0]
            x.append(trainx)
            y.append(trainy)
    for i in range(len(test) - timestamp - 1):

        if len(test[i:i +
                    timestamp]) == timestamp and not np.isnan(test[i:i +
                                                                   timestamp +
                                                                   1]).any():
            testx = test[i:i + timestamp]
            testy = test[i + timestamp:i + timestamp + 1]
            xp.append(testx)
            yp.append(testy)
    return array(x), array(y), array(xp), array(yp)


def lstmwindow(dfData, lags):
    database = split_datasetnormalized(dfData, lags)
    trainX = database[0].reshape(database[0].shape[0], 1, database[0].shape[1])
    trainY = (database[1].reshape(1, -1))[0]
    testX = database[2].reshape(database[2].shape[0], 1, database[2].shape[1])
    testY = (database[3].reshape(1, -1))[0]
    return trainX, trainY, testX, testY
```

though I have a huge file(402k), I am trying to use the first 20000 rows. If I reduce the number of rows significantly, the loss decreases and the accuracy increase. the data can be found at https://gofile.io/?c=PoM9dM

```
trainData = 'data/train.csv'
look_back = 8
df = pd.read_csv(trainData, usecols=['tested'], nrows=20000)
dataset = df.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
trainX, trainY, testX, testY = lstmwindow(dataset, look_back)
```

I used learning rate because it was giving some good results then default setting.

```
opt = Adam(lr=0.0000001, decay=.2)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1028, input_shape=(1, look_back), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mape', 'acc'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=64, verbose=1)


trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
print (trainPredict, trainY)


trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:, 0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:, 0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))


plt.plot(trainY[0][:100])
plt.plot(trainPredict.reshape(-1, trainPredict.shape[0])[0][:100])
plt.show()
```

the results are. After sometimes witha a epoch the loss value is gradually increasing and the accuracy is very low.

```
432/12552 [====>.........................] - ETA: 32s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 992116.1136 - acc: 0.0082 
 2496/12552 [====>.........................] - ETA: 32s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 966677.6248 - acc: 0.0080
 2560/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 32s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 963082.6779 - acc: 0.0086
 2624/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 939593.1212 - acc: 0.0084
 2688/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 957549.8326 - acc: 0.0089
 2752/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 935281.5181 - acc: 0.0087
 2816/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 963213.3245 - acc: 0.0092
 2880/12552 [=====>........................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 941808.8309 - acc: 0.0090
 2944/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 921335.0405 - acc: 0.0088
 3008/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 920601.9731 - acc: 0.0090
 3072/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 901423.1130 - acc: 0.0088
 3136/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 901941.2332 - acc: 0.0089
 3200/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 883902.6478 - acc: 0.0088
 3264/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 887954.1915 - acc: 0.0089
 3328/12552 [======>.......................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 889670.6806 - acc: 0.0090
 3392/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 891472.6347 - acc: 0.0091
 3456/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 907832.6322 - acc: 0.0093
 3520/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 891326.8646 - acc: 0.0091
 3584/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1068598.5278 - acc: 0.0098
 3648/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1089488.1545 - acc: 0.0101
 3712/12552 [=======>......................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1070704.1027 - acc: 0.0100
 3776/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1052556.8863 - acc: 0.0098
 3840/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1035014.4576 - acc: 0.0096
 3904/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1018047.2437 - acc: 0.0095
 3968/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1044726.5623 - acc: 0.0096
 4032/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1047885.8193 - acc: 0.0097
 4096/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1198321.3221 - acc: 0.0095
 4160/12552 [========>.....................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1265580.6710 - acc: 0.0099
 4224/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1302111.3199 - acc: 0.0102
 4288/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1282676.9945 - acc: 0.0100
 4352/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1263814.2721 - acc: 0.0099
 4416/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1254763.8207 - acc: 0.0100
 4480/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1236838.8069 - acc: 0.0098
 4544/12552 [=========>....................] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1244310.3624 - acc: 0.0099
 4608/12552 [==========>...................] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1227028.4810 - acc: 0.0098
 4672/12552 [==========>...................] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1210220.0377 - acc: 0.0096
 4736/12552 [==========>...................] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.0060 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1230652.4426 - acc: 0.0097
 4800/12552 [==========>...................] - ETA: 25s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1214243.8915 - acc: 0.0096
 4864/12552 [==========>...................] - ETA: 24s - loss: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1198267.1610 - acc: 0.0095
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be [overfitting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-and-underfitting-with-machine-learning-algorithms/) your model here which explains the decrease in accuracy and increase in loss. Try parameter tuning. Your learning rate can be higher. Try adding [dropout](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/) to avoid overfitting.

```
from keras.layers import Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```